# Isekai Anime about a schoolboy who dies and wakes up in another world as a prince

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

The anime was on the top of zoro.to a while back. I only remember that in the first episode he kept on calling some famous actress who is also a student by a wrong name and ignored her. She was pissed about it but that's all I remember. And the anime was somewhat simple, slightly less detailed or around the same amount of detail as GATE.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: With questions like this, please include as much detail as possible. For example, "a while back" could, depending on the person, mean 2 weeks, 2 months or 20 years ago. Clearly say "I saw this this year/last year/in the last 5 years" something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

This is [*The Eminence In Shadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eminence_in_Shadow).

The first episode mostly follows a girl in the class of the main character (originally a high school boy living in modern japan). She's a famous actress. The main character does not recall her name, which annoys her.

By the end of the first episode the main character dies in a truck accident, and episode 2 shows him reborn as the son of a Baron (not quite a prince, but close enough) in a different world where magic exists. The anime came out last year and was pretty popular during its run, the manga and light novel both started in 2018.